# Unable to update the value of input box using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to upgrade the value of input box using Javascript or jquery. I could see the value is not forced into the dom. However, I see the change on UI but not in the elements console.

Manually when I am using the keyboard to input the value updates in console. However, I am trying to update using javascript the element console is not updated and change is seen in UI. Refer the attached image.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiwzC.jpg)

Note: The UI code part cannot be changed by me and is controlled by Third party.

```
UI code
    <input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-describedby="auth0-lock-error-msg-email" style="background-image:">
```

```
Jquery
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').val("test")
    });
```

```
Javascript
 let data = document.getElementsByName('email')
 for (elt of data) {
     elt.value = "test";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to select the input by `id`, but it doesn't have any `id` so try with `$('[name=email]')`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('[name=email]').val("test")
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name=email]').val("test")
  console.log($('[name=email]').val())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-describedby="auth0-lock-error-msg-email" style="background-image:">
```

If you want it in JavaScript you can try with:

```
let data = document.getElementsByName('email')
data[0].value = "test";
```

Comment: Value in the console element is still not updating. I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: @Praveen I don't matter since the input still have the correct value, But if you do wish that it is visible in the input then you can "cheat" and use `.attr('value', 'test');`

Comment: @Praveen Run the snippet again and look, it still prints the correct value from the object.

Comment: I did but the console element value is not changing. Although reflecting on the UI. I have built a chrome extension which fills the email and password using javascript and later clicks the log in button. As the value is not forced in the code, click on login doesnt get any value

Answer (score 0):

Your JavaScript code works fine!

```js
let data = document.getElementsByName('email')
for (elt of data) {
 elt.value = "test1234";
}
```

```html
<input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-describedby="auth0-lock-error-msg-email" style="background-image:">
```

Your jQuery code would work if you gave the element the ID you spcified:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#email').val("test1234")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="email" type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-describedby="auth0-lock-error-msg-email" style="background-image:">
```

Comment: Yes, Javascript code works fine but I don't see the change reflected in the Browser elements console as shown in the attached screenshot.

Comment: @Praveen Then you know that the error does not lay in this section of the code. Post more information, if you want help. The code you posted is fine.

Comment: I have built a chrome extension which fills the email and password using javascript and later clicks the log in button. As the value is not forced in the code, click on login doesn't get any value. Does the UI code in the screenshot give any clue ?

Answer (score 0):

add `id="email"` on your input because on your jquery you are selecting by #

`# = 'id'`
`. = class`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#email').val("test")
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" aria-label="Email" aria-invalid="true" value="" aria-describedby="auth0-lock-error-msg-email" style="background-image:">
```